# SQLSTATE[42804] Error when trying to heroku run php artisan migrate

Tags: laravel, heroku, cloud9

I've been trying to `heroku run php artisan migrate` from AWS Cloud9 without any success. How can I fix this problem? I would appreciate it very much if someone could help me. Thanks a lot!

---

I get three errors, all of which are saying

```
SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  column "administered" cannot be cast automatically to type smallint                            
  HINT:  You might need to specify "USING administered::smallint"
```

The migration file in question is as follows:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class ChangeFilariasisMedicationsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('filariasis_medications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('administered');            
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('filariasis_medications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->smallInteger ('administered');
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the related model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 // 追加
use App\AdministeredDate;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable; 
use App\Notifications\ReminderMail; 

class FilariasisMedication extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'start_date',
      'number_of_times',
      'counter',
      'administered'
    ];
    
    protected $dates = [
      'start_date',  
    ];
    
    use Notifiable;

  
    /**
     * この投薬スケジュールを所有するユーザ（Userモデルとの関係を定義）
     */
    public function medication_user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    
    /**
     * この投薬スケジュールに属する投薬確定日（AdministeredDateモデルとの関係を定義）
     */
    public function administered_date()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(AdministeredDate::class);
    }
    
}
```

Current description of filariasis_medications table:
mysql> describe filariasis_medications;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAEjK.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please give us the related model of `filariasis_medications` table

Comment: Thank you for responding BABAK ASHRAFI! I added the information to my question above. I started learning PHP/Laravel two months ago, and there is so much I don't know and understand. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a space before the parenthesis in your migration, remove it.

from `$table->smallInteger ('administered');`

to `$table->smallInteger('administered');`

Comment: Thanks, BABAK ASHRAFI! I didn't notice that extra space at all.